# Inequality for a non negative random variable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, expected-value

For a non-negative random variable $X$ with distribution function $F$, show that $\int_0^{\infty} (1 − F(t))^2 dt \leq (E (\sqrt{X}))^2$?

I was using Holder's inequality to get $\sqrt{E(X^2)} \leq E(\sqrt{X})^2$ but can't proceed further to obtain the LHS. I know $E(X)=\int_0^{\infty} (1-F(t))dt$

Comment: I suspect $\int_0^{\infty} (1 − F(t))^2 dt =E[\min(X_1,X_2)]$ where $X_1,X_2$ are iid like $X$.  Not sure whether it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\min\{x,y\}\leq \sqrt x\sqrt y$ for nonnegative $x,y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are IID, then LHS is $\mathbb E[\min\{X,Y\}]$ while the RHS is $\mathbb E[\sqrt X \sqrt Y]$.